# What is the difference between ConnectionManagement.MaxConnections and ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit?

Tags: performance, wcf

I need to increase the number of concurrent connections that client make and I came across these properties: ConnectionManagement.MaxConnections and ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit. Both are looking same to me. What is the difference?

Answer (score -1):

I am also trying to understand these settings.

I suspect that:

- ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit is used to manage the number of connections that it will open to any host, as it manages and queues ServicePoints.
- <connectionManagement> config "maxconnection" sets a limit on the total number of Pending Requests by host, host group or the all WebRequests in the AppDomain.

So if ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit=200 and //connectManagement[address="*" maxconnections=100], then the effective limit would be 100, ServicePointManager would create 200 ServicePoints, but WebRequest would only allow 100 of them to concurrently have connections.

That is my hypothesis, it needs to be proven.  I suppose I need to read the source code to find out.

I am not finding many blog articles on this subject, here is a lnik to the only one I have found so far.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1979003.aspx?Speeding+Up+HTTPWebRequests+and+the+ServicePointManager